# Application installer tells that my app reads Phone State and identity :-(

Tags: android

Hoi,

I have a simple app with a surfaceview nothing special one would say. However when installing on my phone I get two warnings.

1 - Phone calls
- read phone state and identity
2 - Storage
- modify/delete SD card content.

My really is nothing more than a simple puzzle and I dont understand why I get these warnings.

Any ideas how to avoid this?

Help is very much appreciated,
Kind regards
Jasper de Keijzer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the warnings you mention are user-permissions in the manifest. Check if you have in your manifest lines like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely due to building the app for Android 1.5 (or earlier) and running it on a 1.6 or later device.  According to [this answer](http://gumptravels.blogspot.com/2009/09/ddrescue-ddrescue-gddrescue-gnuddrescue.html) elsewhere on StackOverflow, you can fix it with the following line in your manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
```

It hasn't worked for me, though.